# Opening a file with a .jar

Tags: java, file, jar

Is there away to right click any file in a file browser, go to open with, then select a jar as the program to open the file with? Does doing this pass an argument to the `main(String[] args)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you may create the following batch file

`java.exe -jar path/to/jar/jarfile.jar %*`

and use this file in "open file with"

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it does not. The program will be called with no parameters.

If you want to provide options to your program than you can either:

1. Call your program from a batch file with the parameters included
   OR
2. Your program can ask for the parameters to use once started. This options is better as it is platform independent.

Comment: @Tyecon Please don't forget to mark this as an answer if it helped